# How to send an email with attachment in C#

Tags: c#, email

I created a button that changes the name of fields on a word document.
Now I'd like to send that document in an email with the same button. I looked at many tutorials but none of them were successful

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

    document = application.Documents.Add(Template: @"D:\test\test.docx");

    application.Visible = true;

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field fush in document.Fields)
    {
        if (fush.Code.Text.Contains("Name"))
        {
            fush.Select();
            application.Selection.TypeText(txtE.Text);

        }
        else if (fush.Code.Text.Contains("LastName"))
        {

            fush.Select();
            application.Selection.TypeText(txtM.Text);
        }

        document.SaveAs(FileName: @"D:\test\testsave.docx");

    }
}
```

Comment: why were they not successful?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the problem with the code you've posted? Does it compile? If not, what errors do you get? If so, do you get an error when you run it? If so, what is the specific error? Does it simply not work? If it doesn't work, how does it not work? Does the mail not get sent, or does it get sent without the attachment? If you post code that doesn't work, you need to **be specific** about what the problem is with the code you're posting if you want us to help you. Simply dumping a bunch of code and saying "it doesn't work" isn't quite enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Straight from the horses mouth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public static void CreateMessageWithAttachment(string server)
        {
            // Specify the file to be attached and sent. 
            // This example assumes that a file named Data.xls exists in the 
            // current working directory. 
            string file = "data.xls";
            // Create a message and set up the recipients.
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
               "jane@contoso.com",
               "ben@contoso.com",
               "Quarterly data report.",
               "See the attached spreadsheet.");

            // Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
            Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
            // Add time stamp information for the file.
            ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
            disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
            disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
            disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
            // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
            message.Attachments.Add(data);

            //Send the message.
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
            // Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

      try {
              client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
              Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateMessageWithAttachment(): {0}", 
                    ex.ToString() );              
            }
            // Display the values in the ContentDisposition for the attachment.
            ContentDisposition cd = data.ContentDisposition;
            Console.WriteLine("Content disposition");
            Console.WriteLine(cd.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("File {0}", cd.FileName);
            Console.WriteLine("Size {0}", cd.Size);
            Console.WriteLine("Creation {0}", cd.CreationDate);
            Console.WriteLine("Modification {0}", cd.ModificationDate);
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0}", cd.ReadDate);
            Console.WriteLine("Inline {0}", cd.Inline);
            Console.WriteLine("Parameters: {0}", cd.Parameters.Count);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry d in cd.Parameters)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", d.Key, d.Value);
            }
            data.Dispose();
        }
```